# Perché si chiama "saracinesca" la chiusura metallica scorrente verticalmente che hanno molti negozi?

Tags: etymology

So che l'aggettivo "saracinesco" significa "proprio dei Saraceni" e, per questa ragione, sempre mi è sembrato molto curioso che la chiusura metallica scorrente verticalmente che hanno molti negozi venga chiamata "saracinesca" in italiano. Sapreste dirmi quale sia l'origine di questo uso della parola "saracinesca"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qui bastava aprire un buon dizionario... Per esempio, il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saracinesca/) spiega: «femm. sostantivato dell’agg. *saracinesco*, prob[abilmente] perché ritenute di provenienza saracena, o perché messe alle porte dei paesi costieri per proteggersi dalle scorrerie dei saraceni» e lo Zanichelli conferma più laconicamente facendolo risalire all'espressione “porta saracinesca”, mentre il [Pontigiani](http://etimo.it/?term=saracinesca&find=Cerca), a volte più fantasioso, oltre a questa spiegazione (spiegando meglio come sarebbe stato fatto questo tipo di chiusura saracena), riporta anche l'ipotesi che ci si debba rifare al latino «*sera*, “serratura”, onde prima “Seracinesca”, che leggesi nelle antiche cronache, e poi “Saracinesca”».

Comment: Qualcuno può integrare con il Cortelazzo-Zolli? In generale, per questioni etimologiche, consiglio di cercare in rete sul Treccani, poi sul Pontigiani ma con qualche riserva e poi, se li si ha portata di mano in casa o in biblioteca (oltre a qualsiasi altro dizionario sufficientemente ampio), il dizionario etimologico di Battisti-Alessio e quello più recente di Cortelazzo-Zolli.

Answer (score 2):

Dal Cotelazzo-Colli:

**Saracinesca**:

> Da *saracino* 'saraceno': "l'uso pare venuto o creduto venire dai
>   Saraceni".
>
> Anticamente, cancellata di ferro o di travi calata con catene o funi
>   per sbarrare l'accesso al castello o alla città.
>
> *Porta saracinesca* è attestata nel latino medievale di Treviso nel XIV secolo (P. Sella, *Glossario latino italiano. Stato della Chiesa -
>   Veneto - Abruzzi*, Città del Vaticano, 1944); italiano *saracinesca*:
>   fine secolo XV [?], *Libro di sonetti*; 1514-1520, N. Machiavelli.

Comment: Sono andata nell'unica biblioteca di Barcellona dove si trova questo dizionario (Facoltà di Lettere).